# JMeter: Samples and FAIL issue in HTML Report

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

After generating the HTML report manually (or) by typing Jmeter -g ...csv -e report (or) jmeter -n -t .jmx -l .jtl -e -o report but in the generated HTML Report shows wrong Samples and FAIL this effecting ERROR% in the HTML Report.

In the attached screenshot the total samplers are 268 but in HTML Report it shows 3 and FAIL 2.

Could anyone please help me [image]

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case you have filtering of the transactions enabled somewhere somehow.

Check `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` and `jmeter.reportgenerator.sample_filter` [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)

Example setup:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(your-first-sampler|your-second-sampler|etc)(-success|-failure)?$
```

More information:

- [Generating Report Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)